# opengl - point sprites rendering problem

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm trying to render point sprites but I get points. Where is the problem ? (changing a color via glUniform3f works)

Vertex shader:

```
private static String vertexShader =
"#version 330" + "\n" +
"layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;" + "\n" +
"uniform mat4 pMatrix;" + "\n" +
"uniform mat4 mMatrix;" + "\n" +
"void main()" + "\n" +
"{" + "\n" +
"gl_Position = pMatrix * mMatrix * position;" + "\n" +
"}";
```

Fragment shader:

```
private static String fragmentShader =
"#version 330" + "\n" +
"out vec4 vFragColor;" + "\n" +
"uniform vec3 Color;" + "\n" +
"uniform vec3 lightDir;" + "\n" +
"void main()" + "\n" +
"{" + "\n" +
"vec3 N;" + "\n" +
"N.xy = gl_PointCoord* 2.0 - vec2(1.0);" + "\n" +    
"float mag = dot(N.xy, N.xy);" + "\n" +
"if (mag > 1.0) discard;" + "\n" +   
"N.z = sqrt(1.0-mag);" + "\n" +
"float diffuse = max(0.0, dot(lightDir, N));" + "\n" +
"vFragColor = vec4(Color,1) * diffuse;" + "\n" +
"}";
```

Rendering:

```
gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixUniform, 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);
gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(modelViewMatrixUniform, 1, false, modelViewMatrix, 0);
gl.glUniform3f(colorUniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gl.glUniform3f(lightDirUniform, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
gl.glBindBuffer(GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL3.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL3.GL_POINTS, 0, n_particles);
gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.glUseProgram(0);
```

Comment: I don't see the code where you enabled point sprites or set the corresponding parameters. I'm also not sure if they are deprecated already (could be a problem if you have a core context).

Comment: Solved. I just forgot set glPointSize (with the default value spheres look like points). If point sprites are deprecated in OpenGL 3.3 and above what is the best method to achieve similar effect ? I need an efficient method which can be used to render a particle engine.

Comment: Point sprites were not removed from 3.3 core. But in general, you shouldn't use point sprites because some of their behavior, particularly around clipping, is problematic. On NVIDIA hardware, they follow the rules you would expect. On AMD hardware, they follow the rules that the specification lays out: they are clipped at the center of the point. So if the center is off-screen, the entire point disappears, even if part of it should be visible.

Comment: Using glPointSize make no sense when I'm trying to create some collision detecion etc. There is also problem with scaling when I'm translating point sprites. Maybe I should use some variables in vertex shader which represent a radius for a sphere, a distance and some scale factor. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Lynx If you really want to use point sprites it might be a good idea to compute the point size in the vertex shader, to make it dependent on object space and not on screen space, so that distant sprites are smaller than near ones.

Comment: If I shouldn't use point sprites because some of their behavior, what other techniques can I use to achieve similar effect and efficiency ?

Comment: @Christian Rau: GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION_ARB takes care of that automatically. 

Lynx Lynx: You can use geometry shaders to construct triangles/quads out of a single vertex received

Comment: @edvaldig But I think `GL_POINT_DISTANCE_ATTENUATION` only works with the fixed-function pipeline. At least it's deprecated. And by the way, instanced arrays might also be a good way for sprites: draw multiple instances of a single quad with all other attributes advancing per-instance. Might be faster than the geometry shader, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: `gl_PointSize` can be written in the vertex shader as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do it using a geometry shader?
You simply pass the transformed vertex position to the geometry shader and let the geometry shader output four vertices around that point and you're done.
It's much more flexible and stable.

**Example:**

**Vertex shader:**

```
void main()
{
  gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;

  // Output vertex position
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

**Geometry shader:**

```
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable

uniform float particle_size;

void main()
{
    float halfsize = particle_size * 0.5;

    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TexCoordIn[0][0];
    gl_FrontColor = gl_FrontColorIn[0];

     // Vertex 4
    gl_TexCoord[0].st = vec2(1.0,1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix  * gl_Position;
    gl_Position.xy += vec2(halfsize, halfsize);
    EmitVertex();

    // Vertex 3
    gl_TexCoord[0].st = vec2(1.0,-1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix  * gl_Position;
    gl_Position.xy += vec2(halfsize, -halfsize);
    EmitVertex();

    // Vertex 2
    gl_TexCoord[0].st = vec2(-1.0,1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix  * gl_Position;
    gl_Position.xy += vec2(-halfsize, halfsize);
    EmitVertex();

    // Vertex 1
    gl_TexCoord[0].st = vec2(-1.0,-1.0);
    gl_Position = gl_PositionIn[0];
    gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix  * gl_Position;
    gl_Position.xy += vec2(-halfsize, -halfsize);
    EmitVertex();



    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Comment: Actually I think you could simply multipliate the vertex position with the gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix in the vertex shader, instead of doing it separately in the vertex and geometry shader... I didn't test the code, but it just serves as an example.